# How to replace parts of strings in a list

Tags: python, string, list, replace

i am not so familiar with python, and i don't know how to do this..  So I have a list that looks like this:

```
animal_id = ['id01', 'id02', 'id03', 'id04', 'id05']
```

and I would like to make a new list from the list above, using string manipulation. and the new list should look like this:

```
animal_list = ['a01', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
```

i think i would have to make a for loop, but i dont know what methods (in string)  to use to achieve the desired output

Answer (score 6):

By replacing 'id' for an 'a' in every item of the list, and creating a list containing these items.

```
animal_id = ['id01', 'id02', 'id03', 'id04', 'id05']

animal_list = [i.replace('id','a') for i in animal_id]

print(animal_list)
```

Output:

```
['a01', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
animal_id = ['id01', 'id02', 'id03', 'id04', 'id05']

animal_list = [f'a{x[2:]}' for x in animal_id]
# ['a01', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *list comprehension* and `str.replace()` to change `id` to `a`

```
animal_list = [i.replace('id', 'a') for i in animal_id]
# ['a01', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
```

Expanded:

```
animal_list = []
for i in animal_id:
    i = i.replace('id', 'a')
    animal_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

I iterate the loop till the size of animal_id & split the each element of animal_id with the 'id'. After splitting, it returns the digits value & then concatenate the digits with 'a'.

**Code :**

```
animal_id = ['id01', 'id02', 'id03', 'id04', 'id05']
for i in range(0,len(animal_id)):
    animal_id[i]='a' + animal_id[i].split("id")[1]
print(animal_id)
```

**Output :**

```
['a01', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new list and append to it using string indexing chosing only the last 2 char from original list items

```
new_animal = []
for item in animal_id:
    new_animal.append('a'+ item[-2:])
new_animal

['a01', 'a02', 'a03', 'a04', 'a05']
```

Comment: Will fail for `'id100'`.

Comment: True, just saying indexing can be used or replacing as mentioned in other answers. if number of id is greater than 100 then your answer is the correct one. @Austin